# Objective-C Thread 1:Program received signal: "SIGABRT"

Tags: objective-c, sigabrt

I have an error in this line.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window addSubview:_viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

I'm using Xcode 4.1 and reading Appress Book "Beginning iPhone 4 Development"
Chapter 4.

Regards,
Herman

Comment: Error is not in the above code, I think you should check the viewDidLoad method of _viewController class

Answer (score 1):

Check your IBOutlets. Look if they are all connected and if you see any outlets with an `!` on the right side then delete that outlet, that means that you have connected an outlet earlier, and have deleted it in your header afterwards. That causes a SIGABRT crash. Check the same thing for IBActions.

Comment: I hv double check my IBOutlets all is correct. from the Output it's said this below msg. "Couldn't register ezsnatch.Control-Fun with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all"

Comment: You could have been missing a framework. If you are loading an object embedded in a NIB and it's linked framework is missing you will see this type of behavior.